# $location.path not redirecting from within the controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm striving with a situation where i need to redirect (set new path in browser) after login to profile page.
Below is my code :

/*Below code written in the contoller*/

```
/*Change route to profile page*/
                    var hostname = $location.$$protocol+'://'+$location.$$host;
                    $location.path(hostname+'/patients/profile'); // path take full url including the http
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Main module :

```
var app = angular.module('patientportal',
    [   
        'ngRoute',
        'authentication',
        'forgotpwd',
    'registerform',
    'ngCookies',
    'profile'
    ]
    ).config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$httpProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider,$httpProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          /*
          requireBase: false
          https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase
          */
        });
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type']='application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
        // send all requests payload as query string
        $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){
        if (data === undefined) {
            return data;
        }
        return serialize(data);
        };
    }]);


var authentication = angular.module('authentication',['patientportal']);
var forgotpwd = angular.module('forgotpwd',['authentication']);
var registerform = angular.module('registerform',['forgotpwd']);
var profile = angular.module('profile',['authentication']);

/*
Module profile 
*/
profile.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/profile',{
    templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
    controller: 'ctrlprofile'
  })

}]);
```

**Login controller:**

```
authentication.controller('ctrllogin',function ($scope,$http,$rootScope,$cookies,$location,$window){
    $scope.formdata = {};
    $scope.formdata.action = 'patient_portal_login';
    $scope.formdata.is_web = '1'; //set 1 when login through web.
    $scope.formdata.facility_key = facility_key; //from global scope
    $scope.$parent.heading = 'Login'; //setting the heading

    /*make sure there is no old token stored*/
    $cookies.remove('XSRF-TOKEN');

    $scope.submitlogin = function(){
        //If login form is valid
        if($scope.loginform.$valid){

            postdata = $scope.formdata;
            $("#login_patient").mask('Login..');
            request = $http.post(PORTAL_CONTROLLER,postdata)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $("#login_patient").unmask();
                if(data.status==1){
                    /*Set rootscope values*/
                    $rootScope.root={
                        html_title:HTML_TITLE_PATIENT_PROFILE,
                        loggedin:true,
                        activeProfile:'active'
                    };

                    /*Set the CRSF cookie*/
                    $cookies.put('XSRF-TOKEN',data.token);

                    /*Store the non sensitive information in sessionstorage*/
                    sessionStorage.setItem('states',JSON.stringify(data.states));
                    noty({timeout:1500,layout:'topCenter',dismissQueue:true,text:data.reason,type:'success',killer:true});

                    /*Change route to profile page*/
                    var hostname = $location.$$protocol+'://'+$location.$$host;
                    //$location.path(hostname+'/patients/profile'); // path take full url including the http
                    $window.location.assign('/patients/profile');
                }
                else{
                    noty({timeout:1500,layout:'topCenter',dismissQueue:true,text:data.reason,type:'error',killer:true});
                }
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $("#login_patient").unmask();
                noty({timeout:1500,layout:'topCenter',dismissQueue:true,text:MSG_REQUEST_FAILED,type:'error',killer:true});
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: location path set onky path after '#'

Comment: do you need to redirect to SPA page then just use `$location.path('#/patients/profile');`

Comment: What you must pass to $location.path() (and you should rather use $location.url(), BTW) is one of the paths you have configured in the router. Something like `/patients/profile`.

Comment: @pankajparkar  Router is properly setup if I directly open the /profile URL it is working

Comment: @AngularLearner the same way you should call `/patients/profile` does `html5mode` is enabled?

Comment: @JBNizet $location.url() did not worked either and router if also set on the /profile URL.

Comment: @pankajparkar yes html5mode is set to to true.

Comment: @AngularLearner we can't find a problem with no code and no error message. Post your router configuration, and post the code you're now using. Post any error message you get.

Comment: @AngularLearner then `$location.path('/patients/profile')` would be enough

Comment: Your router path is `/profile`. So just use `$location.url('/profile')`.

Comment: did you try calling $scope.$apply() right after $location.path() ? I came across the same situation once, and calling $apply worked

Comment: @JBNizet
Its strange that $location.path(); returns only / (forward slash) even though My app url is dev.simplifi.org/patients So I was expecting it to /patients

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you so much.. $location.url('/profile/') worked.